# Set Foreign Key Check OFF

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to use this..

```
SQL> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "FOREIGN_KE..."
```

But it say unknown set option

I am using oracle sql 11g express e

I also tried

```
begin
for i in (select constraint_name, table_name from user_constraints where constraint_type ='R'
and status = 'ENABLED') LOOP
execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' disable constraint '||i.constraint_name||'';
end loop;
end;
```

But the console stuck at line 7, not executing or something..

Heres what happen..

Connected.

```
SQL> begin
  2  for i in (select constraint_name, table_name from user_constraints where co
nstraint_type ='R'
  3  and status = 'ENABLED') LOOP
  4  execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' disable constraint '||i.c
onstraint_name||'';
  5  end loop;
  6  end;
  7
```

It show the 7 then no longer work

Comment: What is your prob exactly now? Give us the exact issue what you are facing also indicate the  error line ? in mysql the above command works without any erros

Comment: You don't need the `||''` at the end of line 4.

Comment: *Why* do you want to disable all foreign keys?

Answer (score 2):

if you are attempting to drop tables use:

```
DROP TABLE [TABLE_NAME] CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Comment: ITs `CONSTRAINTS;` or `CONSTRAINT;` ????